# JavaScript: Encapsulate context during loops that create listeners with shared values

Tags: javascript, scope, firebase, listener

Language/Tools For Problem:

Firebase and Vanilla JavaScript

---

**My Problem:**

**When looping**- I'm trying to encapsulate the context of the creation of 2 listeners and a boolean they both manipulate,

**The problems with preserving the context:**

- **Without binding** - the for loop index counter is not encapsulated but ends being the same size of the list.
- **With the binding** - The shared context of the boolean is lost.

---

### **My Code**:

In each loop create 2 listeners and 1 boolean they share

1) `value` - Does the Original Fetch Of Messages

2) `child-added` - Also does Original Fetch(MUST BE SKIPPED) and later gets 
       updates when boolean is set to true

3) `messagesLoaded` - A boolean that signifies that child-added events can now be listened for.

```
//LOOPING THROUGH THREAD IDS EG. [-K1234ASDFADFA,-K43123414234F ]
for(var i = 0; i < threadIDs.length; i++) { //INSIDE LOOP,USING CORE STRATEGY.
  var messagesLoaded = false;

    //FIRST: Load all the Messages of a thread

  var threadRef = firebaseThreadRef.child(threadIDs[i]);
  threadRef.on("value",function(snapshot) {   
    var thread = snapshot.val();
    messagesLoaded = true;
  });

    //SECOND: GET NEW MESSAGES AS THE ARE ADDED

  var messagesRef = threadInstanceRef.child("messages");
  var currentThreadId = threadIDs[i];                  

    //GRABBING TO BIND PARENT ID TO LISTENER

  messagesRef.on('child_added', function(snap) {
    if(messagesLoaded ) {                             
      //MESSAGESLOADED HAS LOST SCOPE!!!!
      var newThreadMessage = snap.val();
      newThreadMessage ["id"] = snap.key();
      receiveThreadMessage(newThreadMessage,this.instanceThreadID);
    }
  }.bind({instanceThreadID:currentThreadId}));

   /*WITHOUT BIND THE CORRECT INDEX 'i' WILL ALWAYS BE THE SIZE TO THE LIST 
    AND NOT WHAT IT WAS DURING THE ITERATION/*

}
```

---

**The Failure in This Code:**

- The bind on the `child_added` was needed to keep the context of `threadsIDs[i]` when it is later fired.
- BUT by binding, `messagesLoaded` is no longer shared between the 2 listeners.

---

**The Question:**

**How can I correctly share "messagesLoaded" between to 2 event listeners?**

---

**Clarifications, if needed, on how the boolean should be used:**

1) `messagesLoaded` is set to false during the loop(initialization-stage)

2) The `on.("value"...` loads and `messagesLoaded` is set to "true"(initialization-stage)

3) `messagesLoaded` sharing the updated context in the `child_added` listener which
   enables it(update-stage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of a shot in the dark because you have a lot going on there, but you're having a combination of issues - specifically async code and a closure in your for loop. This might get you closer.

```
for(var i = 0; i < threadIDs.length; i++) {
  firebaseThreadRef.child(threadIDs[i]).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    var thread = snapshot.val();
    (function(i){
      var currentThreadId = threadIDs[i];
      threadInstanceRef.child("messages").on('child_added', function(snap) {
        var newThreadMessage = snap.val();
        newThreadMessage ["id"] = snap.key();
        receiveThreadMessage(newThreadMessage, currentThreadId);
      });
    })(i)
  });
}
```